# Why does the object fieldname change to the JSON fieldname when the name of the latter is different?

Tags: java, json, spring, angular

I am building a webapp with java/spring on the backend and angular 2+ on the frontend. I have just discovered something very very strange. I have an object called `AffiliateLinkDTO` that is send from the java application to the angular application. When received the JSON is serialized into an `AffiliateLinkDTO` on the frontend side. Both classes are supposed to be an exact mirror image of each other. To be thourough here are the codes of both classes.

AffiliateLinkDTO on frontend side:

```
export class AffiliateLinkDTO {
    constructor(
        public id?:number,
        public affiliateLinkUrl?: string,
        public localizedStoreFront?: string,
        public sellerShipsAbroad?:boolean){}
}
```

AffiliateLinkDTO on backend side:

```
public class AffiliateLinkDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String affiliateLinkUrl;
    private LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront;
    private boolean sellerShipsAbroad;
}
```

As you can see both are an exact image of one another except for a minor detail, the  F of localizedStorefront on the backend is not capitalized like its counterpart on the frontend. Strangely this does not result in an error on the frontside but it gets even weirder.

When on the frontend i printout the field `affiliateLinkDTO.localizedStoreFront` of the `AffiliateLinkDTO` instance it prints out `undefined` but when i print out `affiliateLinkDTO.localizedStorefront` (with a small f) it prints out the value! How is this possible when the field localizedStorefront does not exist on the AffiliateLinkDTO on the frontend??? Even though the class AffiliateLinkDTO is used for instanciating the object the fieldname miraculously changes to `localizedStorefront`. Can anyone give me an explanation please? I'm really puzzled about this. Thank you.

PS: The JSON is not parsed to an AffiliateLinkDTO manually, i am using HttpClient to make a get request to the backend, and the JSON is parsed automatically to AffiliateLinkDTO

EDIT: What i saw was caused by a bug in visual studio, i rechecked to see if i could reproduce what i saw yesterday but i couldn't this time i've gotten a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're doing something like this to create your `AffiliateLinkDTO` instance from the JSON:

```
let dto = new AffiliateLinkDTO();
let obj = JSON.parse(receivedJson);

for(let attr in obj){
    dto[attr] = obj[attr];
}
```

In that case `localizedStoreFront` is undefined because it's never set, because the received JSON only contains an attribute called `localizedStorefront` and not `localizedStoreFront`.

You have two options to  solve this:

- Change the attribute name on the backend class

or

- Add a guard during the instantiation on the frontend to assign the value to `localizedStoreFront` and **not** to `localizedStorefront`

Comment: i'm not doing something like that… I am retrieving the object via `Get request` using angulars `httpClient`. The parsing is done under the hood by `HttpClient` i believe.

Comment: But the concept of the instantiation is the same. The attribute `localizedStoreFront` is not set because your response data does not contain such an attribute. The spelling must be the same.

Comment: yet i get no error and i can still use `localizedStorefront` to get the value!

Answer (score 0):

Maurice, when you make an httpClient.get< Interface>(...) Angular NOT check the value you received. You received you get. the idea of using < Interface> is to help you when write code. If you want you can "map" the response like

```
getAffiliateLinkDTO(id:number):Observable<AffiliateLinkDTO>
{
    return this.httpClient<AffiliateLinkDTO>.get(".....").pipe(
       map(res=>{
          return {
             id:res.id,
             affiliateLinkUrl:res.affiliateLinkUrl,
             LocalizedStoreFront:res.localizedStorefront,
             sellerShipsAbroad:res.sellerShipsAbroad
          }
       })
    )
}
```

Comment: ok this morning i checked again and this time the visual studio ide gives an error when i'm trying to use localizedStorefront instead of Front. So it may have all been due to a bug that arose in Visual studio between seperate reloads of the application after changing something.

Comment: However using `{{affiliateLink.localizedStorefront}}` in an angular material table while the field is defined with a large F still works for some reason..

Comment: I am going to close this thread, i still appreciate all the answers though.. I suppose visual studio had me fooled somehow.

Comment: hmm it seems i cannot delete this thread anymore because others have already replied